# Ordering MySQL query results based on an id value

Tags: mysql, database

I have a questions table and an answers table.  I wont display all fields, but the basic structure is as follows

questions table

```
+-----------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name            | varchar(50)          | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

answers table

```
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| text          | mediumtext       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| question_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

What I am attempting to do is obtain all text answers for a particular set of questions, as one result set.  As such, I am doing the following

```
$sql = "select text, GROUP_CONCAT(text SEPARATOR ',') AS text 
        FROM answers 
        WHERE question_id IN (11, 13, 14, 15, 22, 72);
```

This results in something like this, which seems correct

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [text] => data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6
        )
)
```

However, what I am now trying to do is order this result set in a particular order.  At the moment I have this

```
$sql = "select text, GROUP_CONCAT(text SEPARATOR ',') AS text 
        FROM answers 
        WHERE question_id IN (11, 13, 14, 15, 22, 72) 
        ORDER BY FIELD(question_id, 13, 11, 72, 15, 22, 14);
```

But the result is still in the same order as above.

How can I get the results in the order I am after?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Group_Concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) syntax allows specification of explicit sorting of the expressions/fields being aggregated. In you current attempted query, external `ORDER BY` clause does not server any purpose, as `GROUP_CONCAT()` is effectively aggregating all of them in a single row.

```
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(text 
               ORDER BY FIELD(question_id, 13, 11, 72, 15, 22, 14)
               SEPARATOR ',') AS text 
FROM answers 
WHERE question_id IN (11, 13, 14, 15, 22, 72)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with a subquery:

```
$sql = "select text, GROUP_CONCAT(text SEPARATOR ',') AS text 
        FROM (SELECT text FROM answers WHERE question_id IN (11, 13, 14, 15, 22, 72) ORDER BY question_id) t;
```